# c++: Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Tags: c++, memory, syntax-error

Hello I'm pretty new to coding and have started with my first bigger project just to learn faster.
When I trying too allocate memory the error "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" in the tool tip and then it wont compile.

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H
#include "Headers.h"
#include "Player.h"

class Player;
class Map
{
public:
    Map();
    Player *player; 
    player = new Player;

    std::vector <std::string> levelData;

    void Draw();
    void Create();
    void Open();
    void Save();
};

#endif
```

Comment: If you're new to coding, you should probably spend time with a text book, an editor and a compiler rather than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You probably don't need the pointer. Just make it `Player player;`.

Comment: move "new" to constructor.  `Map(){player = new Player;}`. Class definition can only have declarations and function.

Answer (score 1):

```
Player *player; 
player = new Player;
```

is not right. You cannot have a statement like the second line above in the middle of a class definition.

If you have a C++11 compliant compiler, you can use:

```
Player *player = new Player;
```

Ideally, you should initialize `player` in the constructor of `Map`. That will allow you to avoid `#include`ing "Player.h" in "Map.h".

Also, you should add

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

since you are using

```
std::vector <std::string> levelData;
```